# Display information in CanvasJS using a for loop

Tags: javascript, canvasjs

I want to use information from the API with CanvasJs. I have succesfully shown information in the graph itself only I want to make it dynamic. That's why I wanted to implemend a for loop.

This the code for the loop:

```
var totalValue1 = parseInt('<%= Session["totalValue1"] %>'); 
var monthValue1 = parseInt('<%= Session["monthValue1"] %>'); 
var dateValue1 = '<%= Session["dateValue1"] %>';

var datapointsColumn = [];
for (var i = 0; i < totalValue1.length; i++) {
    datapoints.push({
        x: new Date(dateValue1[i].x),y:totalValue1[i].y
    })
}

var datapointsLine = [];
for (var i = 0; i < monthValue1.length; i++) {
    datapoints.push({
        x: new Date(dateValue1[i].x),y:monthValue1[i].y
    })
}
```

This is the code for the graph itself:

```
data: [{
                    type: "column",
                    yValueFormatString: "€#",
                    showInLegend: true,
                    dataPoints: datapointsColumn
                }, {
                    type: "line",
                    showInLegend: true,
                    yValueFormatString: "€#",
                    dataPoints: datapointsLine
                }
                ]
```

Comment: Can you share the sample data (totalValue1, monthValue1 & dateValue1)?

Comment: Now it overwrites the variable with the new information each time. So it is always one value.